# Windows Dual NIC, bridge interfaces

Tags: windows, networking, network-adapter

It's been a long time since I've used windows and I know basically how to do what I want in Linux but have no idea how to do this in windows.

For work I'm going to find myself [using a dual ethernet mini windows PC](https://www.amazon.ca/Beelink-Computer-Desktop-Display-2-5Gbps/dp/B09DPR1TMR?ref_=ast_sto_dp&th=1). Eth0 would be wired to my router and Eth1 would be connected to a downstream IoT client (specifically an arduino uno with an ethernet shield).

What I want to have happen is that the arduino can connect to the router's LAN, and be visible to the wider network, through the mini pc. From what I understand I simply need to bridge the two interfaces.

Could someone offer some info on how to do this in windows 11 pro?

Answer (score 2):

Open `ncpa.cpl`, select both interfaces, select "Bridge Interfaces" from the right-click menu.

Answer (score 2):

To bridge two network adapters :

- Assign your computer a static IP that is outside the DHCP range of
  the router and not down all details.
  The batch command `ipconfig /all` may help.
- Use the Winkey+X to open the Power User menu and select
  "Network Connections"
- Click "Change adapter options"
- Select both adapters
- Right-click the selection and click "Bridge Connections".
  At this point, the IoT device should have access to the network
  and internet with the IP address information allocated by the router,
  but the Windows computer hosting the bridge won't have internet.
- Now right-click the network adapter in Windows, select Properties,
  click "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and select Properties
- Assign the previous static IP address.

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to set up and manage a Network Bridge connection on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10).